# javafx ComBobox add listener on selected item value

Tags: javafx, combobox

I need to test the value of a selected item to call different methods, so I write this code adding a listener, but the code generate a syntax error

```
@FXML
private JFXComboBox<String> cmbComp;

cmbComp.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<String> composant, String oldValue, String newValue) throws SQLException {
            
            if(/*test item value*/){
                /*do something*/
            }else{
                /*do other thing*/
            }
        }
    });
```

also I don't need an old value and a new one, just test the selected value, how can'I pass arguments ?

Comment: try `ObservableValue<? extends String> composant` instead of `ObservableValue< String> composant`

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html

Comment: it was like that and it generates more errors

Comment: Another remark,changed method should not throw exception as described in the link above. edit your question to show the stack trace generated.

Comment: I can't compile to have a printstacktrace cause it's a syntaxic error

Comment: the error was in the first property calling, thanks

Answer (score 18):

One solution that is a bit more straightforward and avoids some extra lines of code is adding an action listener (ideally from the scene builder) to the combobox, like this:

```
private void comboAction(ActionEvent event) {

    System.out.println(comboBox_DbTables.getValue());

}
```

Comment: Best answer! Thanks

Answer (score 8):

In case anybody missed it, OP answers in the post:

> I found the error, here is the new code, I hope it helps others

```
cmbComp.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((options, oldValue, newValue) -> {
   System.out.println(newValue);
});
```